# Transform price with currency to single number if no numbers after comma

Tags: php, integer

I have a price, let's say `$price = 9,00 €`. If price have 2 zeroes after comma is there easy way to transform it to `9 €` ? I mean is there a function for that or something. If that is not possible with `€` character, how to do that only with integers `9,00` > `9`, but `9,20` would stay `9,20`.

I know it could be done with `substr` or some other ways, but I'd like to know if PHP have function for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de-DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
```

parse it to float

```
$value = $formatter->parseCurrency('9,00 €', 'EUR');
```

check if is *int* or *float*

```
$digits = floor($value) == $value ? 0 : 2;
```

reformat

```
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, $digits);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency($value, 'EUR');
```